# mysqld_exporter DATA SOURCE NAME in mysqld_exporter.service

Tags: mysql, prometheus, grafana

I added mysqld_exporter to prometheus

first I set up a new user in mysql as follows:

```
mysql -u root -p

CREATE USER 'mysqld_exporter'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;

GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'mysqld_exporter'@'localhost';
```

I added a .my.cnf file in `/etc/myslq_exporter`:

```
[client]
user=mysqld_exporter
password=Mypassword
```

then I set up a mysqld_exporter.service in `/etc/systemd/system` as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Exporter Service
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mysqld_exporter
Group=mysqld_exporter
Type=simple
Environment="DATA_SOURCE_NAME=mysqld_exporter:Mypassword@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)"
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mysqld_exporter \
--config.my-cnf /etc/mysql_exporter/.my.cnf
--collect.global_status \
--collect.info_schema.innodb_metrics \
--collect.auto_increment.columns \
--collect.info_schema_processlist \
--collect.binlog_size \
--collect.global_variables \
--collect.info_schema.tablestats \
--collect.global_variables \
--collect.info_schema.query_response_time \
--collect.info_schema.userstats \
--collect.info_schema.tables \
--collect.perf_schema.tablelocks \
--collect.perf_schema.file_events \
--collect.perf_schema.eventswaits \
--collect.perf_schema.indexiowaits \
--collect.perf_schema.tableiowaits \
--collect.slave_status \
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get the mysqld_exporter running, but when I go to localhost:9104/metrics mysql_up is 0

I opened a terminal window and tried these steps:

```
systemctl stop mysqld_exporter
export DATA_SOURCE_NAME='mysqld_exporter:Mypassword@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/'
./mysqld_exporter
```

In this way I succeed to obtain all the metrics, and I got no error in the logs. What is the failure in `mysqld_exporter.service`?

Thanks to all

Comment: Question not useful, it does not expose the error that is visible in the mysqld-exporter logs.

Comment: there was no error in logs, I had only to fix the DATA_SOURCE_NAME to retrieve the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by myself. I had just to replace this line:

```
Environment="DATA_SOURCE_NAME=mysqld_exporter:Mypassword@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)"
```

with this one:

```
Environment="DATA_SOURCE_NAME=mysqld_exporter:Mypassword@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/"
```

then saved the changes, reload the system daemons and restart mysqld_exporter service